# Arduino: Servo "doesn't work" with IR

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to make a little type of "mechanical arm" for my project at school.

My problem is: when the claw gets something the servo stops and the IR goes crazy. I tried everything I know but nothing is working and the project is running late...

This is similar to my project but I don't have the shield:

[image]

```
#include <IRremote.h> 
#include <Servo.h>

#define rec A1 
#define claw 5

Servo g;    
bool i = false;
IRrecv irrecv(rec);
decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  g.attach(claw);
  g.write(25);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); 
}

void loop(){
  if(irrecv.decode(&results)){
    delay(250); 
    Serial.println(results.value);
    if(results.value == 551522925) {
      i = !i;
      change(i);
    }
  }
}

void change(bool i) {
  switch (i) {
    case false:
      g.write(0);
      break;
    case true:
      g.write(25);
      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when the claw gets something the servo stops and the IR goes crazy.

Most probably this is a power problem, Supply the servos from power source different from the Arduino power source and make sure it has sufficient current rating.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to power the servos directly to the battery/power supply. Hobby servos require 4.5-6 volts.
2. By trying to toggle you are complicating the code. Start with using 1 button to open the claw and another button to close it.
3. Remove the `delay(250)`. That stops all code dead for 250mS. I suppose that you are trying to stop the command from repeating and toggling too fast but adding a delay is not going to work. Start by using 2 buttons. Then it doesn't matter if multiple commands of the same type are received.